# Talking in your mind

Tags: waswasa

Assalamu Alaikum Warahmatullahi Wabarakatuhu,

So I go through waswaas quite often and would like to know if this is considered as a major sin or even a sin in Islam.

I get bad thoughts in my mind and then to stop them in my mind I will say 'Stop Shaytaan' or something like that which makes me think like I'm talking to shaytaan. But I do this because I get frustrated with the thoughts I get. please let me know if what I did was wrong.

Jazakallah Khair.

Comment: what kind of bad thoughts ?

Comment: Bad thoughts that I can't even speak of

Comment: Can anyone please help me, Jazakallah Khair.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, you are not punished for something that is out of your control.

And thoughts are notoriously undisciplined. There are several hadiths about it, for example

> Al-Bukhaari (5269) and Muslim (127) also narrated from Abu Hurayrah
>   (may Allah be pleased with him), that the Prophet (blessings and peace
>   of Allah be upon him) said: “Allah, may He be glorified and exalted,
>   will forgive my ummah for whatever crosses their minds so long as they
>   do not act upon it or speak of it.”

**However**, if you *can* do something about it, you should try. In particular, if these evil thoughts you speak of are about physically hurting other people, and if you live in a country that takes these issues seriously (a country where mental illness is not confused with demonic possession), I suggest you consider counsel. For example, I encounter people with tendencies towards pedophilia, who fight hard against these tendencies. There are medications, there are therapy to fight such thoughts. It is extremely hard for them, but as says another hadith, if they do not act upon them, they are rewarded:

> Al-Bukhaari (6491) and Muslim (131) narrated from Ibn ‘Abbaas (may
>   Allah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (blessings and peace of
>   Allah be upon him) said, relating from his Lord, may He be glorified
>   and exalted: “Allah decreed good deeds and bad deeds, then He
>   explained that. Whoever thinks of doing a good deed then does not do
>   it, Allah will write it down as one complete good deed. If he thinks
>   of doing a good deed and then does it, Allah [may He be glorified and
>   exalted] will write it down between ten and seven hundred fold, or
>   many more. If he thinks of doing a bad deed then he does not do it,
>   Allah will write it down as one complete good deed, and if he thinks
>   of it then does it, Allah will write it down as one bad deed.”

I don't know your thoughts, but if they are about hurting other people, and if you think you might act upon them, consider help. 
If the only thing that bothers you is **having** these thoughts, then I don't think you have something to worry about.